# Nodejs imported module is undefined, but works when checked with if statement or when order of import is changed

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I am running into a strange issue.

`xxx.testFunction();` statement when executed errors out: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'testFunction' of undefined`, but works when executed with pre-condition `if(xxx)`..

Issue can be recreated in the following setup

**index.js**

```
const { Module1 } = require("./Module1"); //Commenting out this line fixes the issue 
const { Module3 } = require("./Module3");
Module3.testFunction();
```

**Module1.js**

```
const { Module2 } = require("./Module2");
class Module1 {
    static testFunction() {
        console.log("testFunction")
    }
}
module.exports = { Module1 };
```

**Module2.js**

```
const { Module3 } = require("./Module3"); //Commenting out this line also fixes the issue
class Module2 {

}
module.exports = { Module2 };
```

**Module3.js**

```
const { Module1 } = require("./Module1");
class Module3 {
    static testFunction() {
        //if(Module1) //If we merely check this first it works, but directly it doesn't
            Module1.testFunction();
    }
}
module.exports = { Module3 };
```

Moreover, if some of the `require` statements are removed, the function gets executed..

It **also gets fixed when order of** `require`s in index.js is changed.

If you're wondering why the extra `require`s, the reason is that they were needed for other code in the modules.. The above code is a stripped down version of the production code we found the issue in.

As per my understanding variables in nodejs modules are scoped to the module, and should not have any effect on other modules..

Can someone explain this behavior..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a **circular dependency**. to solve it you can require in the function itself as if you make Module3.js looks like:

```
class Module3 {
    static testFunction() {
            const { Module1 } = require("./Module1");
            Module1.testFunction();
    }
}
module.exports = { Module3 };
```